# does a "fake folder structure" Extension exist in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, processing, vscode-extensions

As an avid user of processing in my spare time, I often find myself writing more than 10 classes in a project, which of course overflows the class bar at the top of the processing IDE and makes it hard to work on all the classes in a project. The solution in any other language is to create class libraries (.net), packages (java), etc. which is not possible from within the processing IDE (It just won't accept .pde files in subfolders).

I tried using Eclipse and importing processing but it makes everything a little more messy as you have to extend Papplet and pass it in to every class that you create and then you have to say parent.rect() or something similar when you want to use Papplet methods which is just one step more than I am willing to go on every new project.

Now, I often use processing from VSCode since i prefer the IDE and i can still compile and debug just as easy from VSCode as Processing IDE, and one day i thought to myself, what if, rather than that horrible solution of using Eclipse, I have the following:

All .pde files are in the one directory (just how processing wants it) but I have an extension for VSCode that takes my files and displays them as if they were in folders within VSCode, There are no changes to the file structure, only the way they are visible to me within the IDE, this way I can comfortably see each of my files and manage larger projects!

So the project folder would look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42v3T.png) in file explorer
But would look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ByZ0.png) in VSCode

So finally, my question is -> Is there some sort of extension that I can get that will do this, if not, any suggestions on where i should start in creating one?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api - I'm glad to use your extension :)